# Razor_imu_9dof callibration: edit arduino code or config file?

Tags: ros, imu, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys
I'm following the indigo instructions for calibration of razor_IMU_9dof and have noted my numbers from the serial monitor calls.  However the docs seem conflicting about what to do with them:   at the start they say put them in the config file, but in the calibration section they say change them in the ardino source. Which is correct? Or do we need to do both?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210728/razor_imu_9dof-callibration:-edit-arduino-code-or-config-file?/) by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2015-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had success with putting them in the config file. The Node does upload them to the imu, with it overwriting any calibration data you put into its flash.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charles.fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/22231/charles.fox/) on 2015-06-09**:
Thanks for clarifying :)    Could anyone tell me how I might update the the documentation to include this, do I need to get edit permissions from someone before I can help?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-06-10**:
Since it is a wiki you can juts edit it, but I would contact the maintainer first.